# I got a good source on the internet, but the images do not appear in JList

Tags: java, swing, icons, awt, jlist

I found a very good code on the internet but when I run, the images do not appear, I downloaded them, put in the project and yet nothing appears, only the text, I'll post a picture I saw on the website that I got the code:

[image]

And now I will post the code, I can not bring up the images, only the text, look at the hiperlink of code:

[Text and Icon in JList](http://andbin.altervista.org/java/examples/awt-swing/list-boxes/TextAndIconList.java)

Thanks !

Comment: Perhaps you are putting them in the wrong location.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If so, then what directory are you putting the files in?

Comment: Very good my friends, that was it, I was missing the directory, I right clicked on "properties" of the picture and I saw the correct directory, thank you! :)

Comment: I'll ask one more question my friends, once done my project, I'm thinking about generate an executable with an installer, which folder or directory, I put on these images to make them along with the project? I create a new directory? I leave on the same project? What do I do? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following code:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

That will show you the working directory of the program you're running, which editors like Eclipse can sometimes mess with. Make sure that you put the files in the exact folder that is shown.

Comment: @RamomMoura Did it work? If so, then can you click the green accept button under the up and down vote arrows?